# Pandas GroupBy.Agg has stopped working due to latest numpy and pandas versions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

My code below seems to have stopped working because of an upgrade to Pandas and Numpy.

df is a pandas dataframe with shape (1000,17).

Example 1: Numpy version is 1.15.0. Pandas version is 0.23.4. The code below works.

```
def percentile(n):
   def percentile_(x):
       return np.percentile(x, n)
   percentile_.__name__ = 'percentile_%s' % n
   return percentile_`

df = df.groupby(by=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8'], as_index=False).agg({'metric1': np.mean,'metric2': [np.mean, percentile(50)], 'metric3': np.mean, 'metric4': [np.mean, percentile(50)]})
```

Example 2: Numpy version is 1.19.0. Pandas version is 1.0.5. The code no longer works (I do not receive an error, cell is stuck on [*]).

Comment: what do you mean just doesnt run?

Comment: @DerekEden the cell is stuck on [*]

Comment: try running it outside of jupyter and see what it says

Comment: The `[*]` makes me think that it will work, eventually. Are any of your grouping keys categorical? You might try adding `observed=True, sort=False` to the groupby call. That can often lead to a major performance increase if a sorted output is not necessary and/or some of the keys are categorical. Not sure if some of those defaults or logic was changed between 0.23 and now.